# PostgreSQL connections constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with two columns, id1 and id2.

If i have for example foo-bar respectively in these columns,I need a constraint that forbids entry bar-foo.

Thanks!

Comment: what version you run?..

Comment: I m using PostgreSQL 9.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id1 integer,
   id2 integer
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON mytable(least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2));
```

This should ddo the trick:

```
test=> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT 0 1
test=> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT 0 1
test=> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2, 1);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mytable_least_greatest_idx"
DETAIL:  Key ((LEAST(id1, id2)), (GREATEST(id1, id2)))=(1, 2) already exists.
```